# Direct User to HTML page after Login

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to simply direct a user to the correct html page after they login. I'm doing this as learning and I know a database with API's is a better method, however in my scenario for now, the User and Password (accounts) are hardcoded.

login.ejs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login_style.css">


</head>
<body>
  <div id="login-form-wrap">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form id="login-form">
      <p>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required></i>
      </p>
      <p>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required></i>
      </p>
      <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()">
      </p>
   </form>
    <div id="footer-wrap">
        <p>WMGSS - Calendar Board</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/loginScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

loginScript.js

```js
const app = express()

function validate(){
    var username=document.getElementById("username").value 
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value 

    if(username =="Young"&& password=="Park"){
        window.location = ("index.ejs")
        return false
    }
    else(null)

}
```

server.js
This states the pages that can be connected to with the correct HTML as their relation.

```js
app.get('/tutorview', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.ejs')
})

app.get('/studentview',(req, res) => {
    res.render('student_page.ejs')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login.ejs')
})

app.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/studentview',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
}))

function setUser(req, res, next) {
    const userId = req.body.userId
    if (userId) {
        req.user = users.find(user => user.id === userId)
    }
    next()
}



app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: You can't call window object from nodejs , its a client side object .

Comment: What the previous comment is saying, is your form needs to be hitting an endpoint (URL) on your backend, then redirecting from there. You seem to be wanting to mix nodejs code with frontend js, which isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was needed, instead of:

```js
const app = express()

function validate(){
    var username=document.getElementById("username").value 
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value 

    if(username =="Young"&& password=="Park"){
        window.location = ("index.ejs")
        return false
    }
    else(null)

}
```

I have done

```js
function validate(){
    var username=document.getElementById("username").value 
    var password=document.getElementById("password").value 

    if(username =="Young"&& password=="Park"){
        window.open("/tutorview")
    }
```